# Special color for "master" git branch name in bash prompt

Tags: git, bash

I have the following in my `~/.bashrc` which make my prompt display `(branch_name) $` in green when I am in a directory using Git.

Example:

```
yoshi@x1carbon:~ $ cd /path/to/git/project
yoshi@x1carbon:/path/to/git/project (master) $
#                                   ^^^^^^^^ this part only in green
```

**What I want** is to display the branch name in yellow instead of green only if I am on master.

This is what I currently have:

```
git_branch() {
  branch=$(__git_ps1 2> /dev/null)
  if [ "$branch" = " (master)" ]; then
     echo "\[\033[33m\]\${branch}\[\033[00m\]" # yellow
  elif [ "$branch" = "" ]; then
     echo "\[\033[31m\] (no git)\[\033[00m\]" # red
  else
     echo "\[\033[32m\]\${branch}\[\033[00m\]" # green
  fi
}
export PS1="\u@\h:\w$(git_branch) \$ "
```

**The problem is** it always display `(no git)`, even if `__git_ps1` in the directory returns the proper current branch name. It seems that `$branch` is always equal to an empty string, whether I am in a dir using git or not.

**The following works** but applies the same color for all branch names:

```
git_branch_simple() {
  echo "\[\033[33m\]\$(__git_ps1 2> /dev/null)\[\033[00m\]"
}
export PS1="\u@\h:\w$(git_branch_simple) \$ "
```

What am I missing here? How can I store the result of `__git_ps1` in a local variable and then test it?

---

**Edit:** Thanks to @ElpieKay, I identified the different problems I had in my script:

- I should not escape the `$` sign in the `echo` instruction:

  ```
  echo "\[\033[33m\]\${branch}\[\033[00m\]"
  #                 ^ removed that backslash
  ```
- `echo` must use the option `-e` to be able to print colors

  ```
  echo -e "\[\033[33m\]${branch}\[\033[00m\]"
  #    ^^ added this option
  ```

Comment: `__git_ps1` already includes the escape codes needed to change the color; try using pattern matching instead: `[[ $branch = *" (master)"* ]]`

Comment: I tried what you suggested @chepner but it did not work. `$branch` seems to (still) be equal to `""` (empty string). How can I "inspect" the `$branch` variable in this context?

Comment: Remove the space in `"  (master)"`.

Comment: @ElpieKay even if I remove it (I tried regex matching too), it does not work. the variable `$branch_name` is always an empty string : this `git_branch` function always put ` (no git)` which means `[ "$branch" = "" ]` returns `true`

Comment: Use `declare -p __git_ps1` or `printf '%q' "$__git_ps1"` to get a better idea of the exact value of the variable.

Comment: What does `echo $PS1` return?

Comment: @chepner when opening a new terminal, I see `''` (because there is no git project in `~/`), but after I change to a git project directory, it outputs nothing, not even the empty string `''`. Does the `printf '%q' "$__git_ps1"` gets called "every new line of the prompt"?

Comment: @ElpieKay `echo $PS1` right after the `export PS1="..."` outputs `\u@\h:\w\[\033[31m\] (no git)\[\033[00m\] $` but only once, as I said in my previous comment it doesn't seem to be called at "each new line of the prompt"

Comment: @MrYoshiji Remove the "\" before `${branch}`.

Comment: And use `echo -e "\033[33m${branch}\033[00m"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this snippet

```
git_branch() {
  branch=$(__git_ps1 2> /dev/null)
  if [ "$branch" = " (master)" ]; then
     echo -e "\033[33m${branch}\033[00m" # yellow
  elif [ "$branch" = "" ]; then
     echo -e "\033[31m (no git)\033[00m" # red
  else
     echo -e "\033[32m${branch}\033[00m" # green
  fi
}
PS1='\u@\h:\w`git_branch` \$ '
```

Comment: It works! what is the difference between `'*git_branch*'` (where `*` equal a backtick, I can't put it in the comment) and `'$(git_branch)'`?

Comment: @MrYoshiji I've update the answer as the "$" before "git_branch" in the last line is not necessary. In theory `\`git branch\`` and `$(git_branch)` should be the same, at least in bash.

Comment: You must be right, I can switch and they produce the same result. What did I miss with my code?!

Comment: @MrYoshiji I made some tests and found that a)`export` is not necessary;b) `echo -e` can print the color and `\[\]` is not necessar;c) the single quotation mark `'` should be used instead of the double quotation mark `"` for `PS1`. I don't konw exactly why but I'd say it's because of the weird bash rules that are beyond my understanding.

Comment: @MrYoshiji To input the backtick, place a backslash before it.

Comment: a big thank you! I think I see now the errors I made in my script, I will update my question to include them